# Bigbluebutton bbb-demo works while the bbb doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, bigbluebutton

Bigbluebutton bbb-demo works while the bbb doesn't work.

I can't use the microphone and I get webrtc error 1004 when I connect from the server itself however when I try the bbb-demo it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

i guess demo might be using flash audio ,please check webrtc port on firewall.

which BBB version you are using ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use VPN? Probably you need a Turn Server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."